# why a class variable is set to nil when itearted in a class method using Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I have the following ruby code

```
class Myown
  attr_reader :num
  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def square_num
    sum = 0
    until (num == 0) do
      sum += num**2
      num -= 1
    end
    sum
  end

  def difference
    square_num - num
  end
end


Myown.new(3).difference
```

It throws an error 
"**undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass**" at square_sum method.

Can anyone explain why this happens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean to use `@num` instead of `num` in that `square_num`, as well as in `difference`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
num -= 1
```

you must do:

```
@num -= 1
```

because Ruby thinks you are trying to access a local variable.

Another option is to use an accessor instead. So you have to change:

```
attr_reader :num
```

to:

```
attr_accessor :num
```

and then do:

```
self.num -= 1
```

Comment: Hi @Agis, 
Thanks for answer.I changed num to "@num" and now the square_sum method works but at difference method the value of "@num" is becoming 0 and it is returning 14 instead 11.